# Find several strings with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for an OR capability to match on several strings with regular expressions.

```
# I would like to find either "-hex", "-mos", or "-sig"
# the result would be -hex, -mos, or -sig
# You see I want to get rid of the double quotes around these three strings.
# Other double quoting is OK.
# I'd like something like.
messWithCommandArgs =  ' -o {} "-sig" "-r" "-sip" '
messWithCommandArgs = re.sub(
            r'"(-[hex|mos|sig])"',
            r"\1",
            messWithCommandArgs)
```

This works:

```
messWithCommandArgs = re.sub(
            r'"(-sig)"',
            r"\1",
            messWithCommandArgs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are for character classes that can only match a single character.  If you want to match multiple character alternatives you need to use a group (parentheses instead of square brackets).  Try changing your regex to the following:

```
r'"(-(?:hex|mos|sig))"'
```

Note that I used a non-capturing group `(?:...)` because you don't need another capture group, but `r'"(-(hex|mos|sig))"'` would actually work the same way since `\1` would still be everything but the quotes.

Alternative you could use `r'"-(hex|mos|sig)"'` and use `r"-\1"` as the replacement (since the `-` is no longer a part of the group.

Comment: `?:` at the beginning of a group means the group is non-capturing.  So you would not be able to reference `\2` in the replacement, because `(?:hex|mos|sig)` means "match `hex`, `mos`, or `sig` but do not save the match to a capture group".

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  Your explanation was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `[]` metacharacters in order to match `hex or mos or sig`. `(?:-(hex|mos|sig))`